# From the collection of all permutation matrices of size $10\times10$, one such matrix is randomly picked. What is the expected value of its trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, permutation-matrices

From the collection of all permutation matrices of size $10\times10$, one such matrix is randomly picked. What is the expected value of its trace? (A permutation matrix is one that has precisely
one non-zero entry in each column and in each row, that non-zero entry being 1.)

I know that possible options for traces are $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$. Now from this how to find the expectation of the trace?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you state how many $10 \times 10$ permutation matrices there are? How many with trace $0$? What about trace $1$?

Comment: Hint: The trace is the number of fixed points of the permutation.

Comment: @Saulspatz Indeed : duplicate of https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Expected_number_of_fixed_points_of_permutation_equals_one with an elegant proof.

Answer (score 10):

Let $A_{ij}$ denote row $i$, column $j$, of matrix $A$.

Let $G$ be the set of $10\times10$ permutation matrices. Then the expected trace is

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{10!}\sum_{A\in G}\text{tr}(A) &= \frac{1}{10!}\sum_{A\in G}\sum_{i=1}^{10}A_{ii} \\
&= \frac{1}{10!}\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{A\in G}A_{ii} \\
&= \frac{1}{10!}\sum_{i=1}^{10}9! \\
&= \frac{10\cdot9!}{10!} \\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$

Note that $\underset{A\in G}{\sum}A_{ii}=9!$, because each permutation matrix $A$ has $A_{ii}=0$ or $A_{ii}=1$. The ones with $A_{ii}=1$ are the ones that correspond to the permutations which send $i\mapsto i$, and there are $9!$ of those.

Comment: How we can say that expectation of the trace is $\frac{1}{10!}\sum_{A\in G}\text{tr}(A)$. please clarify

Comment: The number of $10\times10$ permutation matrices is $10!$. Since we're randomly picking one, each of the $10!$ matrices is equally likely. So for each $A\in G$, the probability of picking $A$ is $\frac{1}{10!}$. Hence the expected value is $\underset{A\in G}{\sum}\frac{\text{tr}(A)}{10!}=\frac{1}{10!}\underset{A\in G}{\sum}\text{tr}(A)$.

Comment: ok. I got it........

Comment: Great! By the way, thanks for posting this really cool problem!